# Запуск SpringMVC приложения в Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

Всем добрый день, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
Пытаюсь запустить созданный в IDEA Spring MVC приложение на Eclipse
Запустил Томкат сервер -> кликаю на проекте Run AS -> По идее там должно быть старт on server, но там только Java Application

Разница, которую нашел в сравнении с работающим проектом на скриншоте, внизу проект где Eclipse как бы видит WEB-INF и там специальные значки напротив файлов context, servlet, web.xml, index.html (этот проект работает), вверху чисто файлы и всё[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как вы провели миграцию проекта?

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду значки в виде желтой "банки" - это значит что файлы находятся под VCS и к Вашей проблеме вроде отношения не имеет

Comment: Я делал File -> Open from existing resources и далее выбирал директорию проекта